# add div in fixed position with 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I need to add two `div` in top and bottom of fixed `div`,so I create `fixed` position panel in left, then add first `div` with `h-100` class(height 100%). But Now, when I add second `div` in panel, I cant see this `div` in result.

```css
.vertical-side {
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1001;
  background: #fbfaff;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}

.second {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="vertical-side">
  <div class="first h-100">
    First div
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    second div
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/92da7tm0/)

I nee to this:

[image: current output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/) utilities. Demo: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bfrnz465/)

```css
.vertical-side {
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1001;
  background: #fbfaff;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}

.second {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="vertical-side d-flex flex-column">
<div class="first h-100 text-center">
  First Div
</div>
<div class="second d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  Second Div
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your expecting, as per your description, you can adjust the height & width as per your need

```css
.vertical-side {
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1001;
  background: #fbfaff;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}
.first {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background:blue;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}
.second {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background:Red;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}
```

```html
  <div class="vertical-side">
    <div class="first">
      First Div
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      Second Div
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, You are basically building in layers - So your second *div* was butted up against your first *div*, whereas you wanted it at the bottom. By putting in a third one in between the two as you can see with my spacer *div* it essentially provides you with margin between your top and bottom *div*s that you can still use and work with later on.

CSS

```
.vertical-side {
width: 250px;
z-index: 1001;
background: #fbfaff;
bottom: 0;
margin-top: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
border-right: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}

.top {
width: 250px;
height: 100px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}

.spacer {
height: 45%;
}

.bottom {
margin-top: 100%;
width: 250px;
height: 100px;
border-top: 1px solid #e9e9ef;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="vertical-side">
    <div class="top">
        <h1>First div</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="spacer">
        <h3>Spacer</h3>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bottom">
        <h1>second div</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image of how it looks

[image]

Edit any specifics you need/want

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you have in class .vertical-side : bottom: 0; and top: 0;
remove  bottom: 0; perhaps this helps</strike>

alternatively you can use grid and change the height here: **grid-template-rows: 1fr 60px;**

or **grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr** for automatic height.

```css
.vertical-side {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 60px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.first {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: grey;
}

.second {
   display: grid;
   margin-top: 2px;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-side">
    <div class="first">
      first
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      second
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd div is under your first div, which is 100% of its parent height. that means the 2nd div is out of the viewport. use flex/grid for your parent div (vertical-side). you'll find the 2nd div. use a height for your first div. that will also solve the issue.

[image]